# mysql query error when have '(' but no ')'

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
$q = "select * from product where decription = ?";
$param = 'package ( 2 chicken wings, 3 salad';

$result = DB::select($q, array($param));
```

there is an error query because the param string don't have ')'..
how to prevent query if there is '(' but no ')' in string?

error message : Syntax error or access violation: 1064 syntax error, unexpected $end

Comment: Which kind of error are you facing? Try looking up the error message

Comment: error message : Syntax error or access violation: 1064 syntax error, unexpected $end

Comment: Have you tried something using the query builder like : `DB::table('product')->where('description', $param)->get();`?

Comment: You should escape the string with "\" i.e ` "select from product where decription  \'?\' " `

Comment: an error cause by ')' that from sthe string 'package ( 2 chicken wings, 3 salad'.

Answer (score 0):

Look, you dont have $query.. that would be $q not $query

The answer is `$result = DB::select($q, array($param));`

Comment: the problem not form $query variable...the main error from ')'.. after I edit the string adding ).. it work normally.. error message : Syntax error or access violation: 1064 syntax error, unexpected $end

Comment: your query is false... select what from product ?? if you want all the query is "Select * from product"

Comment: Why are you using RAW SQL Querys.. with laravel you can work with eloquent